# want to know how to use startswith in python dataframe by considering two columns

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy-slicing

My input is (A, B Have data, and need output in C column).

Logic is. If my first four letters in A and B columns are INKA or IDKA then Out put is KAR.

Same way INAP or IDAP then AP and INRJ or IDRJ then RAJ

The input is A and B, and the expected output is C.

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| IDKA106829_KMGL_H_Z_8121 | INKA100345_KMGL_H_Z_8251 | KAR |
| IDKA101971_KUDU_H_Z_8251 | YEDTHADY-IND | KAR |
| SIRA_RPTR | IDKA102853_KSIR_H_Z_8251 | KAR |
| IDAP104327_PEDA_H_Z_8251 | IDAP104769_URUM_H_Z_8251 | AP |
| IDAP103547_RAMP_H_Z_8251 | MADDIRALA | AP |
| SALURU | IDAP103620_SALU_H_Z_8251 | AP |
| IDRJ103411_KOTA_H_Z_8251 | KOT009 | RAJ |
| IDRJ100041_BKNR_H_Z_8251 | INRJ200420_BKNR_H_Z_8251 | RAJ |
| JAIPR203 | INRJ200420_BKNR_H_Z_8251 | RAJ |

Comment: Did you mean that one of A and B values need to be 'INKA' for example, or both of them?

Comment: if any of both column value is inka or idka then result shuld be KAR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `np.select`:

```
conditions = [(df["A"].str[:4].isin(["INKA", "IDKA"]))|(df["B"].str[:4].isin(["INKA", "IDKA"])),
              (df["A"].str[:4].isin(["INAP", "IDAP"]))|(df["B"].str[:4].isin(["INAP", "IDAP"])),
              (df["A"].str[:4].isin(["INRJ", "IDRJ"]))|(df["B"].str[:4].isin(["INRJ", "IDRJ"]))]

df["C"] = np.select(conditions, ["KAR", "AP", "RAJ"], None)
```

Alternatively, you could use `map` and `combine_first`:

```
mapper = {"INKA": "KAR", "IDKA": "KAR", "INAP": "AP", "IDAP": "AP", "INRJ": "RAJ", "IDRJ": "RAJ"
df["C"] = df["A"].str[:4].map(mapper).combine_first(df["B"].str[:4].map(mapper))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with a iterations, starts with, and if else! like so!

```py
dataframe = [
['IDKA106829_KMGL_H_Z_8121','INKA100345_KMGL_H_Z_8251',''],
['IDRJ100041_BKNR_H_Z_8251','INRJ200420_BKNR_H_Z_8251','']
]

for row in dataframe:
    for column in row:
        if column.startswith('IDKA') or column.startswith('INKA'):
            row[2] = 'KAR'
        elif column.startswith('INJR') or column.startswith('IDRJ'):
            row[2] = 'RAJ'

print (dataframe)
```

Comment: Looping is not efficient

Answer (score 0):

With the use of [startswith](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) and [np.select](https://predictivehacks.com/pandas-how-to-assign-values-based-on-multiple-conditions-of-different-columns/).

```
conditions = [df['A'].str.startswith('INKA') | df['B'].str.startswith('INKA') | df['A'].str.startswith('IDKA') | df['B'].str.startswith('IDKA'),
              df['A'].str.startswith('INAP') | df['B'].str.startswith('INAP') | df['A'].str.startswith('IDAP') | df['B'].str.startswith('IDAP'),
              df['A'].str.startswith('INRJ') | df['B'].str.startswith('INRJ') | df['A'].str.startswith('IDRJ') | df['B'].str.startswith('IDRJ')]
 
choices = ['KAR','AP', 'RAJ']
 
df['C'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=None)
```

Result df:

[image]

Comment: Please data/output as *code* and not *screenshots*.